# Why I still have FileNotFoundException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement?

Tags: java, swing, file, try-catch

For my application, I keep getting this compilation error saying `**FileNotFoundException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement**` I have this within the actionlistener event handling part so I'm not sure whether it's the correct way to do it.

I do understand that the catch exception bit is related to the try statement and it must be so called related so in this case, I'm initiating a new File object class from the user's input but the error stays.

Could you guys give me some advice as I'm still a novice and I just started on `GUI` not long ago?

Main class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class MyFileLister extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private JLabel prompt = null;

private JTextField userInput = null;

private JTextArea textArea = null;

public MyFileLister()
{
    prompt = new JLabel("Enter filename: ");
    prompt.setOpaque(true);
    this.add(prompt);

    userInput = new JTextField(28);
    userInput.addActionListener(this);
    this.add(userInput);

    textArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
    textArea.setOpaque(true);
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    this.add(textArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

Scanner s = null;
File af = null;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f)
{
    try
    {
        af = new File(userInput.getText());
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
}
```

And the driver class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


class TestMyFileLister {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    MyFileLister thePanel = new MyFileLister();

    JFrame firstFrame = new JFrame("My File Lister");

    firstFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    firstFrame.setVisible(true);
    firstFrame.setSize(500, 500);
    firstFrame.add(thePanel);


}
}
```

Comment: Change the `FileNotFoundException` to just `Exception`

Comment: @mickey That's wrong and bad programming practice. That File constructor throws a NullPointerException if the path argument is null, not FileNotFoundException. Change to NPE and you'll be all right.

Comment: I disagree that it is wrong and it was just a suggestion to get Scorpioran going. Once the exception is caught, then it could be changed to something more specific when s/he sees what it is.

Comment: @mttdbrd thanks for giving me a better advice :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the [constructor of File taking a String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) can only throw a `NullPointerException`.

> public File(String pathname)
>
> Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string into an abstract pathname. If the given string is the empty string, then the result is the empty abstract pathname.
>
> Parameters:
>       pathname - A pathname string
>
> Throws:
>       NullPointerException - If the pathname argument is null

Change your `catch` to

```
catch(NullPointerException e) {
```

and act accordingly.

Comment: @Jonathan Drapeau useful information and lets me understand why I'm having this error. cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The `java.io.File` object just represents an abstract path. Whether a file (or directory) denoted by it exists or not is irrelevant at its creation time.
The constructor of `File` does not check whether the path points to an existing file or folder.

It only matters if you want to open the file. Then you would get a `FileNotFoundException` (if it doesn't exist).

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear: the statement `af = new File(userInput.getText());` does NOT throw `FileNotFoundException` (at any time). Java allows you to create `File` object that does not exist on your file system. How would you create a new file if not ;) So your `try catch` block is useless here. You might want to change the exception type to `NullPointerException` so you can handle case when `null` is passed to `File` constructor.